# connectionstring to sqlmembershipprovider asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have added the sqlmembershipprovider to my dynamic data project for logging in and registering and such.

However, I am having problems with the connection string. The database is on a remote sql server 2008 database server.

Below I have a connection string for the entities:

```
<add name="xxEntities" 
connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=xx.xx.x.xxx;Initial Catalog=XX;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I hit the membership provider, I get this error:

Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

on this line of code:

System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers(0, 1, count)

Do I need a separate connection string for the provider? Or should I be able to use the above string with all my connections, including my membership provider?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this connectionString template + change the User-ID, Password, Initial Catalog

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;User ID=RemoteApp;Password=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;
```